# Automation testing for Edge Legacy in C#

Tags: c#, testing, automation, microsoft-edge, winium

I want to run automation testing on Edge Legacy (not Chromium) but need the option to also change the browsers settings in the process, specifically the Theme and the Cookies settings.
I tried using [Winium.Cruciatus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Winium.Cruciatus/) but was unable to even run the browser's executable.
Is there a different library that allows these kinds of actions for automation testing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to use Microsoft WebDriver to automate the MS Edge legacy browser.

It is a suitable solution for automation.

If you are using the builds prior to 18 then you can refer to the link below to download the appropriate version of a web driver.

[Download WebDriver for MS Edge browser](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)

Microsoft WebDriver for Microsoft Edge version 18 is a Windows Feature on Demand.

To install run the following in an elevated command prompt:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Web driver will get installed on the location below.

```
C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
```

You also need to download the necessary NuGet packages in your C# project.

Here is a sample code to launch the MS Edge legacy browser.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver();
driver.get("https://example.com");
```

You said that you need the options to change the browser settings in the process,
specifically the Theme and the Cookies settings.

You will not able to modify most of the browser settings using selenium automation. Few browser settings are available to modify using automation. You can use Selenium automation to fully automate the webpages.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but we are already using Selenium for the actions in the web pages, but we don't have a solution for the browser settings yet

Comment: Most of the browser settings are not available for automation. So it is not possible to automate it. I am not aware of any library that can let the user modify browser settings using automation.